# Seeking advice to conceptualize the completed machine learning product and leave the Jupyter Notebook behind

Tags: machine-learning

I have a well functioning sports betting model that is my obsession, but it exists only inside a jupyter notebook. I have a long ETL function that pulls and arranges the data from two separate APIs, and prepares them for the model which I run daily.

I'm seeking advice on which technologies to use for the database (I'm currently just loading, adding to, and re-saving CSV files through pandas) , how that connects to my ETL function, and which cloud service to prop it up on.

The end goal is a fully automated model for which I can create a simple UI (Dash or Flask?) that spits out daily predictions and displays historical results.

Thanks so much.

Comment: this is a vast general question..